# Using Android Studio's logcat better, permanent focus on a single process?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, logcat

When testing on a device in Android Studio you get an awful lot of output in the logcat.

I'm only interested in the output for the app I'm developing. I can see just this, after running, by opening the *Devices* section and manually selecting my apps process. Problem is, it's pretty tedious to do this every time I run my app, which seems to be the case.

Is there a way to get it to remember this setup?

How about a way to get it to stop reporting anything after I'm done with my app or it's crashed ? (otherwise my app specific stuff gets buried so quickly by output from other proccesses on my phone)

I'm open to other ways of filtering the logcat too, however I couldn't think of a way to set up filters so that I would get my tagged Log messages **AND** other exceptions I wasn't expecting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this is done by default, but if not,

in logcat, the green plus sign, when you click it you get a dialog, fill the `byApplicationName` with your package name, and also your `filter name` with something, now you can filter your output according to your app

with that beeing said, sometimes you don't get the filter column info (`application` name) in logcat at all (blank), here (and I my self don't know the cause of it) just forget it for a while and retry again

Comment: Not quite what you said but you made me give the filter box another look and I sorted it out: I clicked `Edit Filter configuration` on the filters drop down and added my complete package name like so `com.bitbucket.hollyzorx.myapp` in the `by Package name` box and that seems to have done the trick! 

Thought I'd give you the rep but you might want to mention my comment in your answer for future users.

Comment: absolutely, glad I could help a little